# Setting up a computer as a gateway

Tags: firewall, internet

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question

Currently i have this set up

PC 1 and PC 2 are connected by a switch on the same subnet which is connected to a router.

I would like to connect to internet via this route

PC 1 - > PC 2  -> router

However, i tried configuring my default gateway and DNS address as the ip address of PC2 but it does not work.

I am using windows 7 and have disabled firewall on PC 2

Comment: First, I would caution that you absolutely need to have a firewall on the WAN link. Second, for a consumer device such as a PC, you need to ask this question on Super User. Questions about consumer-grade devices and home networking are both specifically off-topic, but both are welcome on Super User.

Comment: Why is traffic from PC1 going to PC2? You are better off to use a switch and Connect all of your devices to it. One interface on the router will connect to the switch and the other interface of the router will connect to your modem/Internet.

Comment: Hi i have a switch but there are traffic which i need PC2 to verify before passing it to the router

Answer (score 2):

You can either choose to turn on ICS or do the following:
Go to Start and search on cmd or command. Right click on either cmd or command then select Run as administrator. At the command prompt type regedit. Navigate to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter setting, right click and select Modify